# What ARM tablet can I run regular Ubuntu and XBMC and hook up an external HDD...?

Tags: tablet, xbmc, arm, nas, home-theatre

I want to run XBMC on an ARM Tablet, using bluetooth keyboard and an external 4TB hard drive to substitute a typical HTPC.

.
P.S.: HTPC doesn't exist as a tag... can someone who is not new here create it?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an external HDD to the (officially supported) nexus 7 and 10 and play videos. XBMC is not yet available for Ubuntu Touch (as far as I know). There is an XBMC for Android though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and info!  <br/>
<br/>
I don't want to run Ubuntu touch actually, I want to run regular Ubuntu with XBMC.  
<br/>
The Android version of XBMC is just a satellite to an XBMC server on some other machine...  
<br/>
wow, its swallowing all my line breaks...